# SQLite exception : no such column found ( id primary key)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have two tables in my database and I use inner join to print out data to LogCat which satisfying conditions.
I sure, it is just a foolish mistake.

Caused by:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: position.id (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select people.name as Name, position.name as Position, salary as Salary from people inner join position on people.posid = position.id where salary > ?
```

How I create two tables:

```
public static final String TABLE_POSITION = "position";
public static final String TABLE_PEOPLE = "people";

public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

public static final String KEY_SALARY = "salary";
public static final String KEY_POSID = "posid";


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_POSITION + "(" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key," + KEY_NAME + " text," + KEY_SALARY + " integer" + ");");
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_PEOPLE + "(" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement," + KEY_NAME + " text," + KEY_POSID + " integer" + ");");
}
```

How I fill out position table:

```
cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(databaseHelper.TABLE_POSITION,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < position_id.length; i++){
            contentValues.put(databaseHelper.KEY_ID,position_id[i]);
            contentValues.put(databaseHelper.KEY_NAME,position_name[i]);
            contentValues.put(databaseHelper.KEY_SALARY,position_salary[i]);
            sqLiteDatabase.insert(databaseHelper.TABLE_POSITION,null,contentValues);
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
```

Data for position table:

```
    int[] position_id = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    String[] position_name = { "CEO", "Programmer", "Teacher", "Policeman" };
    int[] position_salary = { 15000, 13000, 10000, 8000 };
```

Data for people table:

```
String[] people_name = { "Ivan", "Maria", "Petr", "Anton", "Daria", "Boris", "John", "Suzy" };
int[] people_posid = { 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4 };
```

Error on this line:

```
String sqlQuery = "select people.name as Name, position.name as Position, salary as Salary from people inner join position on people.posid = position.id where salary > ?";
        cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sqlQuery,new String[]{"12000"});
        logCursor(cursor); //priting out cursor to LOG.d
        cursor.close();
```

I know that id without autoincrement is autoincrementing also, but I have to know id in position table for inner join as I suggess. So, how to solve this error? I know it is only primary key/autoincrement error

Comment: The error says that there is no column `id` in table `position`. The most common cause of this error is that you have ran before the app with another name for this column. Once the database was created later you changed the name in your code but this change did not affect the database. Just uninstall the app and rerun so the database is recreated.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, i just have to remove database and launch app again. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved people.posid = position._id ..But no data in tables.. (after two hours of thoughts)